# Your tags couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, quality-filter

I am trying to edit a post to improve it, but cannot:

- [Get the count of numbers doubling using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27259096)

> [image]

I am editing posts *a lot* and I know the message well. But this time it is

a. wrong
b. blocking

That's new. I have tried multiple times. Edited just tags or just the body or the title. It blocks all the time. First observed around 15 minutes ago.

It may be relevant that in my first attempt to edit I changed the title to start with an upper case letter and then got an error message in yellow / brown ranting about the (now?) duplicate title. All further attempts were blocked as described.

Comment: Related problem on another site: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1461/49

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to submit posts with validation warnings again after build rev `2014.12.3.2063` rolls out.

Comment: Silly question, but as a bit of a noob to all this stuff, when do these builds roll out? Obviously the date is today, but are builds done at a certain time of day, or rolled out randomly at different times, or something completely different? Just curious.

Comment: @AndrewMartin the last part is an incrementing number. Builds are triggered manually.

Comment: Incrementing? Then why I see "rev 2014.12.3. **2820**" at the bottom?.. That should be reported as bug then? :)

Comment: @nicael because some meta sites are on the meta tier (tiers: dev -> meta -> prod), each tier has it's own incrementing _build_ number, that's why [I usually give](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243933/editing-an-answer-to-a-question-while-writing-an-answer-makes-the-answer-this-q/244478#244478) 2 build revs

Comment: Yes, edit went through with the new build. Seems fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @nicael there's also stackexchange.com, area51, and data explorer, each with its own different build. :)